# pandas.Series results in nan values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset in pandas (named naa)

```
   id  cod                data  nivel_mont  nivel_jus
```

0     naa    1 2002-10-28 00:00:00      162.10        NaN
1     naa    1 2002-10-29 00:00:00      162.10        NaN
2     naa    1 2002-10-30 00:00:00      162.34        NaN
3     naa    1 2002-11-01 13:00:00      162.10        NaN
4     naa    1 2002-11-02 15:00:00      162.20        NaN
...   ...  ...                 ...         ...        ...
6166  naa    1 2021-02-13 00:00:00      165.20        NaN
6167  naa    1 2021-02-14 00:00:00      164.20        NaN
6168  naa    1 2021-02-15 00:00:00      162.40        NaN

doing

a = naa.iloc[:, 2]
b = naa.iloc[:, 3]

valores_naa = pd.Series(data=b, index=a)
print(valores_naa)

results in

data
2002-10-28 00:00:00   NaN
2002-10-29 00:00:00   NaN
2002-10-30 00:00:00   NaN
2002-11-01 13:00:00   NaN
2002-11-02 15:00:00   NaN
..
2021-02-13 00:00:00   NaN
2021-02-14 00:00:00   NaN
2021-02-15 00:00:00   NaN
2021-02-16 00:00:00   NaN
2021-02-17 00:00:00   NaN
Name: nivel_mont, Length: 6171, dtype: float64

why the `NaN` values? I was expecting the values of column 'nivel_mon'

thanks

Comment: Use `naa.set_index(naa.iloc[:, 2]).iloc[:, 3]`

Comment: In your solution `pd.Series(data=b.to_numpy(), index=a)`